# Can the holographic surface of our universe be located at the cosmic horizon?

Tags: holographic-principle

I just listened to a Susskind's talk at Stanford, where, as an answer to a question, he said that may be the surface that contains the information to describe our 3D universe might be located at the cosmic horizon. But what if for whatever reason at the distance of the cosmic horizon space were empty? Then how could that surface contain any information about the physics inside?

Comment: I think (intuitively) that the holographic surface of our universe rests on the hyper black hole's event horizon contains us.

Comment: But that is only if you believe/assume we are in a black hole.